# sphinx tmp and new files issues

Tags: sphinx

I'm using sphinx version 0.9.9, I'm getting error in an index which was working fine since couple of years, it started to give errors last night when i looked in to the issue it was making **.new.sp*** and **sp*.tmp**. i used a trick for **.new.sp*** files when i rotated it 3-4 times and it did't replaced **indexname.sp*.new** files to **indexname.sp*** i renamed **indexname.sp*.new** to **indexname.sp*** manually and it was giving results but automatically it was not renaming files also same scenario for tmp files. any idea?? i tried to change folder and but result was same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked deeply into the case and found solutions,
There was no disk space issue on server, Searchd service was probably crashed due to that existing indexes which were rotation during that time was unable to rotate properly, so when searchd service restared after recovery it made .new.sp* files. this issues was solved after restarting searchd service.
Second issue was for tmp files, so i found .tmp files during index rotation as soon as index completes rotation .tmp files are gone.
It was fun solving own issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Does the disk definitly have enough diskspace? Maybe it never quite finishes building the index due to a full disk.

In general you need 2-3x the size of the biggest index free.